# success: function(data) in jquery is never executed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, google-api

I do an ajax call in jquery function in order to post a form to the controller. I checked that all the fields have the right value, but

```
sucess : function(data) {
    alert('it works');
}
```

doesn't show anything.Here is my code :

```
function add_event() {
    // Vars
    var form_values = $('#addEventForm').serialize();

    // Traitement Ajax
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo site_url()."/public/calendar/addEvent/"; ?>',
        data: form_values,

        success: function(data) {
            // Debug
            alert(data);

            if (data == 'true') {
                $('#addEvent').hide();
                location.reload();
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        },
    });
}​
```

Here is my code in the controller:

```
function addEvent()

{       $this->load->library('gcal');

    // Posts      
    $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $click_date = $this->input->post('start_date'); echo $click_date;
    $date       = explode("-", $click_date);
    $year       = $date[0];  
    $month       = $date[1]; 
    $day        = $date[2]; 
    $date_start = $this->unix_timestamp($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);
    // Params
    $params = array(
                        'calendarId'    => 'myriam.gsim@gmail.com',
                        'allday'        => true, 
                        'start'         => $date_start,
                        'end'       => $date_start,
                        'summary'       => $title,
                        'description'   => "this is a test"
                    ); 
       echo 'before insertion';
    // Insertion
         $response = $this->gcal->eventInsert($params);
    echo 'apres insertion';


    if($response)
    {
        echo "true";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "false";
    }

}
```

I noticed that it is `$response = $this->gcal->eventInsert($params);`which causes the error(I registered the app on google api console)

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Have you also checked the server response?

Comment: Are you getting this values in server ?

Comment: I assume you're using CodeIgniter. Have you tried removing the slash in front of `public`? As far as I remember `site_url()` already adds a trailing slash. Otherwise check the request with Chrome DevTools, Firebug or similar.

Comment: maybe check the error like this: `error:function(a,b,c){ alert(c); }`, which will help debugging

Comment: @Thomas It doesn't matter how many slashes you add, you can build a path even with //////public///calendar//

Comment: @Simon, it does when a framework parses the url "stupidly", because the first variable in //public/calendar/.../.. is empty and this could trigger an not found...

Comment: @Thomas The function addEvent in my controller isn't called correctly I think. I removed the slash in front of public but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: As we have no indication of any framework with a JS preprocessor here (never heard of one) I must ask you if this JS code is embedded in your HTML header (written in a php file) or in a separate JS file. Because if separated, your php call would not be executed.

Comment: The js code is actually embedded in my HTML header (the form and the jquery functions are in the same file)

Comment: Why do you think that addEvent() isn't called correctly? Show us the code in which you call addEvent(). What happens if you call addEvent() in the console?

Comment: Use the Network Panel in Firebug/F12 tools to check the server response when the ajax post is run.

Comment: @jfrej If I called it directly I get errors because this function needs the values posted by the jquery function.And I think it's badly called because I tried echo ('something') in the beginning of the function but nothing is printed.

Comment: How about your serverside script?

Comment: What's actually the name of your controller, public or calendar? Can you post the addEvent function?

Comment: my controller is : controllers/public/calendar.php. The jquery function is in views/content/calendar/calendar.php (it's a codeIgniter project).The problem isn.t with addEvent, even an echo '' isn't executed

Answer (score 0):

Add a fail with it...

For example:

```
$.ajax({ ..
..
..
success: function(data) {alert(data)},
error:function(request, status, error){// do something with it..}
})
```

I am pretty sure, it is failing. Also check your Console for extra information.

Comment: it is failing and data doesn't contain anything. However, alert(form_values) print the right value. Does that mean that data:form_values isn't executed ?

Comment: That means that your URL is not returning what it should return. Try inputing the url directly  and see what happens. Does the page load correctly? Also, did you check the Firebug console?

Comment: Yeah, the page loads correctly when I input the url directly. However, could you please have a look on my post? I posted my function addEvent in the controller, The ajax call fails because of $response = $this->gcal->eventInsert($params);